# thymeleaf +spring date converting

Tags: thymeleaf

[image: This is my data model]

This is my data model. I want to use date from here.

I do this in my html:

```
<table th:if="${!commentsInTask.empty}">

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="Comments : ${commentsInTask}">
    <tr th:each="comment : ${Comments}">
        <td th:text="${comment.user}">user ...</td>

        <td th:text="${comment.createdAt}">date ...</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but it  brings:

```
<table>

    <tbody>
         <td>JACK</td>

        <td>1.476787930289E9</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This part is unix timedate:
1.476787930289E9

but in the picture at beginning i posted, you saw. Timme is not that.

This is in domain

```
    public String getCreatedAtString() {
        return createdAtString;
    }

    public TaskComment setCreatedAtString(String createdAtString) {
        this.createdAtString = createdAtString;
        return this;
    }
private ZonedDateTime createdAt = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

Why cantt i see in date format which in picture at the beginning?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use Thymeleaf formatting:

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(comment.createdAt, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')}">date</td>
```

You'll get an output in the following format: `18-Oct-2016 14:44:05`.

`#dates`: methods for `java.util.Date` objects: formatting, component extraction, etc.

---

To convert your `createdAt` field to `java.util.Date` type use:

```
Date date = Date.from(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant());
```

Or just use `java.util.Date` type:

```
private Date createdAt = new Date();
```

this will set `cheatedAt` to current date.

---

Also you can add [thymeleaf-extras-java8time](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time) dependency to your project to work with your `ZonedDateTime` type.

This module adds a `#temporals` object similar to the `#dates` or `#calendars` ones in the Standard Dialect, allowing the formatting and creation of temporal objects from Thymeleaf templates:

[image]

Then you can use `ZoneDateTime` with the specified pattern:

```
${#temporals.format(temporal, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')}
```

See more at [Thymeleaf - Module for Java 8 Time API compatibility](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/blob/3.0-master/README.markdown).

Comment: 18/10/2016 13:51 w hat about this?

Comment: It will be `dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm`. You can use any pattern there, please look for more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(comment.createdAt, 'dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm')" (task_comment_cta:33)

Comment: I got this error ' org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(comment.createdAt, 'dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm')" (task_comment_cta:33)'

Comment: that's because type of `createdAt` is `ZonedDateTime`. I've updated an answer, check it pls.

Comment: SO, are not there any ways to use only in html code without using java dates?

Comment: There is also another way to use `java.time` types in Thymeleaf. But then you need to add another dependency to your project. Look for my updated answer.