# Why can't I use my LocalDate date from the Class in Thymeleaf ${#dates.format(date,'dd/MM/yyyy')}?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

The date out of my Class should be dd/MM/yyyy format in thymeleaf HTML.
It seems that the Thymeleaf date format method doesn't recognize my LocalDate from the class.
It is an exercise, I am not allowed to change the format in the Class.

```
<ul >
   <li th:each="i:${#numbers.sequence(0(gemaakteCursus.aantalDagen)-1,1)}">
    <span th:text=
    "${#dates.format(gemaakteCursus.getStartDatum().plusDays(i),'dd/MM/yyyy') 
    }"/>
    
  </li>
</ul>
```

The ERROR says: [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(gemaakteCursus.getStartDatum().plusDays(i), 'dd/MMM/yyyy')" (template: "cursusinfo" - line 21, col 15)] with root cause :
Method call: Method format(java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.thymeleaf.expression.

Thankyou to help me out!

Comment: The Thymeleaf `#dates` utility is for Java `Date` objects ([see the documentation here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-utility-objects)). You are not using a `Date` - you are using a `LocalDate`. Therefore you need to use the Thymeleaf `#temporals` utility object (see the documentation [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time)). This is in a [separate JAR file](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time).

Comment: Related: [thymeleaf +spring date converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106875/thymeleaf-spring-date-converting).

Comment: @andrewjames Thankyou for the solution with the #temporals.format(date,'dd/MM,yyyy'! It works